# Read from socket until receiving message, removing event listener, then returning synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous

I am having a bit of trouble with creating one function. I have two sockets. I want to write to one, which should trigger the other to begin output. I want to wait until receiving a specific reserved token to return, synchronously, and unbind the event listener.

```
execute: function (command) {
  check(command, String);

  // wait for the "okay" message on the messages socket
  this._messages.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
    // if nothing comes back in 10 seconds, time out.
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
      var parse = data.toString('ascii').split(':');
      if (parse[0] === 'End') {
        // Receiving 'End' means the command was successful unbind this event handler and return
        return 0;
      }
    }, 10000);
    return 1;
  }));

  // send the command to the command socket
  this._commands.write(`XQ#${command}\r`);
}
```

The problem I am having is forcing it to block until it receives this data, then unbinding the callback when the appropriate data is received or time out occurs.

I might be doing this wrong. It does kind of seem like unregistering a callback from... within the callback is basically like lifting a chair that you're already sitting on... but what is the appropriate way to handle this use case?

Comment: Just don't do this. Don't fight asynchrony. Embrace it!

Comment: They shouldn't be able to do anything until the function finishes, so I ideally want to block it on the client until it finishes

Comment: Who is "they"? You surely don't mean "the client should freeze until the function finishes"

Comment: Well, it runs on the server, but they shouldn't be able to do the same action directly afterwards

Comment: Sure, then do that (by disabling the submit button or whatever on the UI, by using a semaphore on the server, etc). But you don't want to freeze either browser nor server (especially as there might be other connections at the same time)